# good and free 3D modeling programs for implement into Unity

Tags: unity, game-design, 3d-modeling, csg

I'll make some objects that are not easy to make in Unity, but on my previous question [Making holes in 3D objects (Unity)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113800/making-holes-in-3d-objects-unity) was there an answer that said that I can make it whit an other 3D modeling program.

So my question is now in witch 3D modeling program can I use for make 3D figures on a **simple** way, can be **implement into Unity**, **has [CSG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry)** modeling options and can I download and use **for free**? Here is a list:

- SketchUp
- ArchiCAD
- Blender
- FreeCAD
- IntelliCAD
- Maya
- Tinkercad
- ZBrush
- MoI3D
- Autodesk 123D
- Hexagon 2.5
- GtkRadiant
- Leadwerks Engine
- Roblox Studio - Since 2014
- UnrealEd
- Valve Hammer Editor
- ... for everything I've forgot.

Or is it better to use free and simple Unity plug-ins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the best Unity-specific level-editing tools is [ProBuilder](http://www.protoolsforunity3d.com/). Tools like Maya and Blender are generally my recommendation for 3D art, but you did ask for CSG.