# Make a door in a cube-wall

Tags: unity

I have created a wall using a cube in Unity. Now I want to create a door in it.

How can I make a door in that cube?

Consider that the cube is automatically generated, so i have to generate the door in a C# script.

Comment: While I'm not really happy with the answers, this question is likely a duplicate of this one: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113800/making-holes-in-3d-objects-unity

Comment: I think it is not. Please consider that the door has to be auto-generated: so there is a coding part, not only modelling part.

Comment: The cube mesh is automatically generated? Or it's a prefab with a cube mesh? You need to know how to cut a hole in the cube, and put a door model inside the hole?

Comment: The world itslef is completely autogenerated from code. It has a cube prefab with its cube mesh. Yes, I have to cut the cube and put a door model in it

Comment: Right, so how is it different from cutting a hole in an existing mesh? Surely you already know how to place the door model once the hole is cut.

Comment: I am a beginner in using Unity. So I'm not very expert in mesh manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Unity primitives are not like actual 3D models, they are great for concepts but do not afford much versatility. I recommend that you start with changing your original wall prefab.

- Create an empty game object and in it make 3 cubes.
- Next, arrange the cubes to look like a wall with a space for the door.
- Make a prefab of this object, maybe name it "wall"

Now make a new cube and size it to fit the hole in the wall.
Keep an eye on the transform position in the upper right-hand corner.

You should probably make a prefab of the door object as well.

In C# you'll want to create a "public transform door" this will be visible in the inspector. You can then Instantiate the door at the position you need the door to be. That should look something like:

Instantiate (door, door.position, Quaternion.identity);

In the unity inspector you'll want to drag and drop the door prefab in slot that appears as the door transform.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The moment where one starts building complex objects from cubes and other primitives in the Unity editor is the moment where one should really consider picking up a 3d modeling program.

Comment: @Philipp I upvoted both the question and answer, because this was a problem I had before, and the solution I used. But your comment is the right thing to do. I wish it was a suitable answer.